# python script ignoring newlines in a files

Tags: python, shell

The following contents are in a file.i use a shell script to call a python script.This python script send the mail.But in the mail contents i see the  output as shown below.Its all in oneline..What am i doing wrong

```
 /usr/bin/python $DIR/sm.py "$message"  "`cat /tmp/alert.txt`"
```

Input:The following are the contents of alert.txt

```
  Thu Jun 28 14:29:26 IST 2012

  Disk usage limit exceeded -Current disk usage is 167G-Configured disk usage is 200HTTPD connections exceeded configured usage limit -Current HTTPD connections is 21-Configured HTTPD connection is 20


  ========================OTHER INFO==================
  Total fds: 8
  Socket fds: 0
  Other fds: 8
  Free memory :Free Memory:183732
  Buffered memory Buffered Memory:78224
  Cache memory : Cache Memory:579040
  Disk usage is 167G
  DB connections 1
  Network connections 21
  CPU Usage: 0.0
```

Output:

```
  Thu Jun 28 14:29:26 IST 2012 Disk usage limit exceeded -Current disk usage is 167G-Configured disk usage is 200HTTPD connections exceeded configured usage limit -Current HTTPD connections is 21-Configured HTTPD connection is 20 ========================OTHER INFO================== Total fds: 8 Socket fds: 0 Other fds: 8 Free memory :Free Memory:183732 Buffered memory Buffered Memory:78224 Cache memory : Cache Memory:579040 Disk usage is 167G DB connections 1 Network connections 21 CPU Usage: 0.0
```

This is sm.py

```
import logging
import smtplib
import sys
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart


      try:
         smaid = qs[0].id
         gmailUser = 'no-reply@xxxxxxxxxxx.com'
         gmailPassword = '12345'
         mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
         mailServer.ehlo()
         mailServer.starttls()
         mailServer.ehlo()
         mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)

         to_addr = "xxxxx@xx.com"
         subject = sys.argv[1]
         body = sys.argv[2]
         try:
             msg = MIMEMultipart()
             msg['From'] = gmailUser
             msg['To'] = to_addr
             msg["Content-type"] = "text/html"
             sub = subject
             msg['Subject'] = sub
             body = body

             msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
             mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, to_addr, msg.as_string())
         except:
             write_exception("send exception")

         mailServer.close()
     except:
          write_exception("send exception1")
```

Comment: What's in sm.py ? 

python /tmp/test.py "`cat /tmp/test.py`"
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])

does work.

Comment: Yes i am using sys.argv to get the subject and the body of the mail..

Comment: Please add the contents of sm.py

Comment: I don't see where in the script you actually produce the given output. Also. that script is not valid Python (for example, Python doesn't have a `Pass` keyword. Also, don't suppress exceptions!

Comment: The sm.py will send a mail to specified address

Comment: `msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))` I guess you are sending as HTML, so try replacing `\n` by `<br />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on sending HTML, you need HTML line breaks:

```
import cgi
# escape special HTML characters
body = cgi.escape(body)
# use HTML line breaks
body = body.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "<br />\n")
```

But probably you need neither Multipart nor HTML, so you can just use [`smtplib.SMTP.sendmail`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail):

```
headers = (('From', gmailUser), 
           ('To', to_addr), 
           ('Subject', subject))

# normalize newlines to CR+LF, as required by SMTP
body = body.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\r\n")

msg = '\r\n'.join("%s: %s" % kv for kv in headers) + '\r\n'*2 + body

mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, [to_addr], msg)
```

Also, you should not supply the file contents via the command line, because the command line  is length-restricted. Instead you should supply the file via STDIN, like in `python ... < /tmp/alert.txt` and read it via

```
import sys
body = sys.stdin.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

Send it as `text/plain` instead of `text/html`.
You do not have any HTML there.
That should fix it, because it's up to client to show the text correctly then. New lines do not have the same effect in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You set the mail's content type to "text/html", so the user's mail-agent will obviously interpret and render the body as html. If you want to preserve plain text formatting, just don't set the content type to text/html.

Answer (score 0):

Which shell are you using?

```
"`cat xxx`"
```

in csh will remove all the newlines and return a space separated string

```
> cat >testfile
line 1
line 2
<ctrl-d>
> echo "`cat testfile`"
line 1 line 2
```

Comment: Try `echo "\`cat testfile\`"`

Comment: depends which shell you are using. in csh, it does what I said

Comment: sh, Bash and zsh (the most commonly used) do it differently. Agreed though that depending on this is risky. Better pass the file via STDIN or by filename